# Build for IOS through AppCenter fails for a react-native app

Tags: ios, react-native, continuous-integration, cocoapods, visual-studio-app-center

Recently I have integrated AppCenter for CI & Distribution in one of my react-native projects.Android is working fine.I am facing issues in iOS.Particularly I am not able to take build for iOS.The issue is pod installation gets failed. Anyone who has integrated AppCenter for iOS successfully pls do help me out. I will add the screenschot of the error below:

[image: Pod installation failed]

Comment: What's the RN version?

Comment: @DmitriiChichuk its 0.60.5